# Cancellable set of asynchronous operations with progress reporting in iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, progress, operation, cancellation

Suppose that I use another SDK (which I do not have control of) with an API that imports 1 file asynchronously, and calls a completion callback on completion.
The following is an example API.

```
func importFile(filePath: String, completion: () -> Void)
```

I need to import 10 files (one by one) using this API, but I need it to be cancellable, e.g. after Files 1,2,3 has been successfully imported, while File 4 is being imported, I want to be able to cancel the whole set of operations (import of the 10 Files), such that File 4 will finish (since it already started), but Files 5-10 will not be imported anymore.

In addition, I also need to report progress of the import. When File 1 has been imported successfully, then I should report progress of 10% (1 out of 10 has been finished).

How can I achieve this?

I am considering using NSOperationQueue with 10 NSOperations, but it seems that progress reporting will be difficult.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I think we can also use `dispatch_suspend` to resolve this. Are you looking for a solution based only on NSOperation?

Comment: I edited my answer in such a way that it answers all your queries. I humbly request you to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe that this is the following you want from your question:

1. Import n files one by one in a queue
2. Report progress when each file is imported
3. Ability to cancel operation in the middle

It can be achieved using `NSOperationQueue` and `NSBlockOperation` in the following way.

1. Create `AsyncBlockOperation` and `NSOperationQueue+AsyncBlockOperation` classes from code given in answer for the following StackOverflow question: [NSOperation wait until asynchronous block executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889861/nsoperation-wait-until-asynchronous-block-executes)
2. Import both the classes into the file they are going to be used
3. Create an operation queue

   ```
   NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
   operationQueue.name = @"com.yourOrganization.yourProject.yourQueue";
   ```
4. Create a function which gives you a callback for getting progress

   ```
   - (void)importFilesFromFilePathArray:(NSArray *)pathsArray
                       inOperationQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue
                           withProgress:(void (^)(CGFloat progress))progressBlock {

     }
   ```
5. Inside the function defined in `2`, use `NSBlockOperation` for performing your operations in the `NSOperationQueue`

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < pathsArray.count; i++) {

       [operationQueue addAsyncOperationWithBlock:^(dispatch_block_t completionHandler) {
           [self importFile:(NSString *)[pathsArray objectAtIndex:i] completion:^(bool completion) {
               [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                   CGFloat progress = (100 * (float)(i+1)/pathsArray.count);
                   progressBlock(progress);
                   if (progress == 100) {
                      successBlock(YES);
                   }
                }];
                completionHandler();
            }];
        }];
   }
   ```
6. For cancelling operations, we can simply use the `operationQueue` that we created in the 1st step

   ```
   [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
   ```

I tried this code myself. It's working well. Feel free to suggest improvements to make it better :)

Comment: Looks good. But what will you do if *importFile* is asynchronous, as stated in the problem description? And, how about the completion callback when all operations have been completed, how do you address that requirement?

Comment: I'll add that in a few minutes

Comment: If you get a progress of 100, then that means it is successful right. Here, failure reporting becomes difficult when you have an option to manually cancel the operations. Small doubt: If one of the files importing gets failed, should we continue or should we cancel all the operations?

Comment: Also, since your `importFile` function is asynchronous, you can use https://gist.github.com/msealand/b90e621ad5420bc4f2bf instead of normal NSOperationBlock

Comment: I see, so you are suggesting an asynchronous type of implementation for a subclass of NSOperation. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer in such a way that it answers all your queries. Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` offers a nice object oriented abstaraction and is the way I would go.

- Create a `NSOperationQueue`named `importQueue`

For each import:

- Create a `NSOperation`
- Store the operation to reach and possibly cancle it later on, for instance in a dictionary [ImportNumber:NSOperation]
- Add the operation to `importQueue`

---

In regards to the progress state:

Option 1:

`NSOperationQueue` has a property called `operations`, whichs count you are able to observe. (`importQueue.operations.count`).

Option 2:

`NSOperation` offers completion blocks. You can increase a counter when queueing the operation and decrease it within the completion block or when cancelling.

---

Further reading: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation), [asynchronous-nsoperation-why-and-how](http://swiftgazelle.com/2016/03/asynchronous-nsoperation-why-and-how/), [nice but oldish tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift).

Comment: How will you implement NSOperation for an asynchronous API (as stated in the problem description)?

Comment: A concrete implementation would be too long and imo. SO is not meant to offer this. If you have questions after reading the tutorial, let us know, maybe in a new question for specific new issues you are running into.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not asking for a concrete implementation. A brief answer is okay. The question explicitly dictates that the API (from a 3rd party SDK) is asynchronous, and your answer uses a synchronous API.

Comment: An NSOperation can run synchronous (or non-concurrent) and asynchronous (or concurrent). All well explained well in the mentioned tutorial.

Comment: The NSOperations (ImageDownloader and ImageFiltration) in the tutorial you mentioned use synchronous APIs only. What asynchronous APIs are you referring to?

Comment: I added more links. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add dependencies on your operation.
The idea is this:

```
1Op = NSOperation..
2Op = NSOperation..
.
.
10Op = NSOperation..

10Op.addDependency(9Op)
9Op.addDependency(8Op) and so on...
```

Then your operation subclass should override the cancel method in this way

```
cancel() {
    super.cancel()
    for dep in dependencies {
        dep.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: How about progress reporting and completion callback?

Comment: Inside your operation you can call progress update delegate