# How to know all concurrent NSOperations are completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation, nsblockoperation

My situation is:

- I have users
- Each user has some history data that can be fetched via user objects

What I want to do is:

- Max 2 users must be fetching their history data at the same time (this is the reason that I want to use NSOperationQueue)
- I need to get notified when any user finished fetching its history data
- I need to get notified when every user finished fetching their history data

What I ask is:

- How can I achieve what I want to do since I can't make it thru with the code below?

Any help is appreciated.

```
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];

    for (User *user in users) {
        NSBlockOperation *operationObject = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            [user loadHistoryData:^{
                [NSNotificationCenter postNotificationToMainThread:@"oneUserFetchedHistory"];
            }];
        }];

        [operationQueue addOperation:operationObject];
    }
```

This question differs from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333640/ios-concatenating-asynchronous-block-based-operations) because I don't want to chain any requests. I just want to know when they are all finished executing.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27918833/4168746) has a completion block for only one operation queue.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126799/4168746) offers a way to make operation block to wait until async call to `loadHistoryData` is completed. As writing `setSuspended`

I could not find an answer for my need. Is there any?

Comment: I've edited my question. I don't think this question is a duplicate @matt

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1407971-waituntilalloperationsarefinishe?language=objc

Comment: But the problem is that method not waiting for async operations to be completed in a block operation? @TheNextman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [AsyncBlockOperation](https://github.com/devxoul/AsyncBlockOperation) and [NSOperationQueue+CompletionBlock](https://github.com/devxoul/NSOperationQueue-CompletionBlock)

Combining them is working for me like this:

```
  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
  [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]; 
  // 1 is serial, more is concurrent

  queue.completionBlock = ^{
    [NSNotificationCenter postNotificationToMainThread:@"allUsersFetchedHistory"];
  };

  for (User *user in users){
   [queue addOperationWithAsyncBlock:^(AsyncBlockOperation *op) {
     [user loadHistoryData:^{
       [op complete];
       [NSNotificationCenter postNotificationToMainThread:@"oneUserFetchedHistory"];
      }];
    }];
  }
```